# Flutter: IconButton onPressed responding in console but not in the display

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter and trying to build a responsive web app.  So far, the code I have working is when the screen shrinks in width to a certain size, the navigation bar and its items get crunched into a menu icon button (Flutter's IconButton).  This works.  What doesn't work is when I click the IconButton, the new navigation bar doesn't pop up, even though the console shows I'm clicking on it.  DrawerItem() is just a Text Widget wrapped in a Container.  After the couple sections of code, you can see the console spitting out a response.  I do not get any errors on screen or in the console when I adjust the screen size or when I click the IconButton.  I've also tried making the MNavigationBar a stateful widget and adding setState to the onPressed attribute, nothing changes from the current issue and the same thing happens.

```
class MNavigationBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const MNavigationBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 80,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.menu,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              NavigationDrawer();
              print('Menu Icon pressed');
            },
          ),
          NavBarLogo(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class NavigationDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigationDrawer({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 260,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black,
            blurRadius: 16,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          NavigationDrawerHeader(),
          DrawerItem('Home'),
          DrawerItem('Events'),
          NavBarMenuDropdown(),
          DrawerItem('Store'),
          DrawerItem('Partners'),
          DrawerItem('About Us'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
Performing hot restart...                                          148ms
Restarted application in 149ms.
Menu Icon pressed
Menu Icon pressed
```

Comment: The line NavigationDrawer() under the on pressed function is just creating an instance of your NavgationDrawer stateless widget. You are not drawing the widget anywhere. You should set the Navigation Drawer as the drawer property in your base Scaffold widget and then use Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer() in the onPressed function

Comment: @AfridiKayal See my code change below.  Your suggestion worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, Afridi Kayal!  I did exactly what you said and it works great!  See the answer in the code below...

In my main Scaffold widget, I added this code and also added logic with a ResponsiveBuilder

```
return ResponsiveBuilder(
      builder: (context, sizingInformation) => Scaffold(
        drawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,
        drawer: sizingInformation.deviceScreenType == DeviceScreenType.Mobile
            ? NavigationDrawer()
            : null,
```

In my MNavigationBar, I modified this.

```
onPressed: () {
              Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();       
              print('Menu Icon pressed');
            },
```